# need to click on a specific location in between an image using selenium

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where i need to click on a specific location in between an image. On analyzing through Firebug its showing as an image and given id as "Panel_"

```java
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 

// taking mouse to 00   
builder.moveByOffset(0,0).build().perform();

// then clicking on the x y cords of the image. This XY i have taken from one tool.    
builder.moveByOffset(1076,560).click().build().perform();
```

Or

```java
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("Panel_"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
int clickAtX = 1076;     
int clickAtY = 560;     
builder.moveToElement(target,clickAtX,clickAtY).click().build().perform();
```

But neither of the code fragments is helping me. Sometimes it says clicking outside of  page range. 
I used "Mofiki's Coordinate Finder" tool to get the xy coordinates.

**Is there any other way to do this?**

Comment: Try integrating sikuli script with selenium. It will be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the response Hemanth. Could you please give a code example to achieve this? tnx again,

Comment: check this link http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html . you will get some idea. We can just capture the part of image where we need to click and tell sikuli to click on the same image.

Comment: Hemanth-- My question is I need to click on specific region (cords) of the image not whole image at once, like if there is one image "Google" I need to click on G then o. when i am trying to get id of the particular region its giving me whole image id, Can I do this using sikuli? thanks again for looking into this. :)

Comment: Sikuli does not need any id or xpath. it just needs the image. If we take your example, you need to capture two images, one containing "G" and other containing "O". Sikuli, blindly clicks on the images.

Comment: But, The concern is the "Google" is a single image in my code. then?? :(

Comment: but you can crop the image and make 6 different images for all the letters in GOOGLE :) and sikuli will click on whatever image you give it as input. Also, did you try using xpath or css which you can capture using firebug? If possible share the application link. i'll debug the issue.

Comment: as i said its just returning the xpath of the full image. And I CAN'T change the image, its coming from third party, This is internal site so not able to show on web.